# I created a template for a scrollable page and a non-scrollable page. Is there a way I could combine these and use a param to set scrollable or not?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code I am using:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public partial class ScrollHeadingView : ContentPage
{

    public ScrollHeadingView()
    {
        var outerGrid = new Grid();

        var scrollView = new Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView() { 
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always 
        };
        var contentView = new ContentView()
        .Bind(ContentProperty, nameof(InnerContent), source: this);
        scrollView.Content = contentView;
        outerGrid.AddChild(scrollView, 1, 0);
        Content = outerGrid;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public partial class HeadingView : ContentPage
{

    public ScrollHeadingView()
    {
        var outerGrid = new Grid();

        var contentView = new ContentView()
        .Bind(ContentProperty, nameof(InnerContent), source: this);
        scrollView.Content = contentView;
        outerGrid.AddChild(contentView, 1, 0);
        Content = outerGrid;
    }
}
```

Is there some way that I could combine these and have a parameter:

```
"Scroll = true" or 
"Scroll = false"
```

with a default of true?

Here is the way the class is used:

```
public partial class DecksTabPage : ScrollHeadingView
{
    public DecksTabViewModel vm;
    public DecksTabPage()
    {
        BindingContext = vm = new DecksTabViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        vm.OnAppearing();
    }

}
```

and

```
<t:ScrollHeadingView
    x:Class="Views.DecksTab.DecksTabPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Templates"
    x:Name="ThisPage"
    GearIconTapCommand="{Binding GearTapComd, Mode=OneWay}"
    GearIconVisible="true" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties).

Something like

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty IsScrollableProperty = BindableProperty.Create (nameof(IsScrollable), typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollHeadingView), null);

public bool IsScrollable
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsScrollableProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsScrollableProperty, value); }
}
```

then in you could set the `IsScrollable` in your xaml:

```xml
<t:ScrollHeadingView
   ...
   IsScrollable = True
/>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a bit more than just the binding which I know how to do.  I guess what I would like to have is a suggestion on how I could change the code of public partial class HeadingView.  In a few hours I will open up a bounty for this so.  Thanks

Comment: Can you suggest the next step which is how to change the code to accept and use the IsScrollable.  I understand that you have added it as a binding however I don't see how to make the change to the scrollable property based on that binding.

Comment: I assume I need to bind the IsScrollable to VerticalScrollBarVisibility but how can I do that.  Also I assume it's not needed to use a property changed and when I did try a property changed it didn't fire when IsScrollable = True is set in the Xaml.  It only fired if I added that in the C# behind after initialize.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ScrollHeadingView(bool scroll = true)
{
    if (scroll) {
      ...
    } else { 
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I explained a bit more in my question by showing the usage.  How can I specify the scroll = true in XAML for this?

Comment: it you want to do it via XAML you will need to make it a property, not a constructor parameter

Answer (score 1):

We can use the orientation property of ScrollView to make the content scrollable. So, if we don't want to scroll then we can set Scroll = False and it will work as normal view and when we set Scroll=True then it will work as scroll view.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public partial class ScrollHeadingView : ContentPage
{

    ScrollView scrollView;
        public static readonly BindableProperty ScrollProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Scroll), typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollHeadingView), true,BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: (obj, oldValue,newValue)=> {
            OnScrollPropertyChange((ScrollHeadingView)obj,(bool)newValue);
        });

        private static void OnScrollPropertyChange(ScrollHeadingView view,bool newValue)
        {
            if (newValue)
        {
            view.scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;
            view.scrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always;
        }
        else
        {
            view.scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Neither;
            view.scrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Never;
        }
        }

        public bool Scroll
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ScrollProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScrollProperty, value); }
        }

    public ScrollHeadingView()
    {
        var outerGrid = new Grid();

        scrollView = new Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView() { 
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always 
        };
        var contentView = new ContentView()
        .Bind(ContentProperty, nameof(InnerContent), source: this);
        scrollView.Content = contentView;
        outerGrid.AddChild(scrollView, 1, 0);
        Content = outerGrid;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<t:ScrollHeadingView
    x:Class="Views.DecksTab.DecksTabPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Templates"
    x:Name="ThisPage"
    GearIconTapCommand="{Binding GearTapComd, Mode=OneWay}"
    GearIconVisible="true" 
    Scroll="False">
```

Comment: OnScrollPropertyChange does fire with Scroll="False" or Scroll="True" in the XAML.   Can you instead of using the ispropertychanged come up with a solution that involves binding to VerticalScrollBarVisibility and sets that based on the IsScrollable?

Comment: means you want to hide the VerticalScrollBarVisibility when Scroll="False"?

Comment: Yes, plus completely turn off scrolling but through binding, not through property changed.  Binding allows me to use Scroll="False"> in the XAML.  Property changed requires me to code in Scroll=false after the page is initialized.  Property changed doesn't appear to work when Scroll="False" is added to the XAML.

Comment: Scroll is Bindable property. Default value of Scroll Property was false in my code that's why when you set Scroll="False" then property changed does not fire because value is not changed. Now I have changed it to True. Now it will work. Please check.